# Pre-built functions for Financials or pattern recognition

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to find the following pattern in a dataset.

Starting Point
--Find the Lowest Low--Find the Next highest high--Find the Next lowest low
(Keep repeating the above pattern) until the dataset ends.

I see there are built-in pattern matching functions in other RDBMS but I could not find something similar I can use in postgres. Or perhaps if there is a financial extension that I can use for my requirement, that will be helpful as well.

If anyone can point to references it's greatly appreciated.

Sample Dataset:

```
Test Run     Data Value
1                23
2                24
3                 25
4                22
5                21
6                20
7                30
8                32
9                 36
10                22
```

So the output I am expecting is

- Start (1,23)
- lowest low (6,20)
- highest high (9,36)
- end (10,22)

Thanks for the sample but perhaps I did not give a complete picture on the sample dataset... So here is one... with a few more line items as sample............. 
(1 , 23),
 (2 , 24), 
(3 , 25), 
(4 , 22), 
(5 , 21), 
(6 , 20), 
(7 , 30),
(8 , 32), 
(9 , 36), 
(10 , 22), 
(11, 25), 
(12,28), 
(13,30), 
(14,45), 
(15,30), 
(16,34), 
(17,35);

output 
start (1,23) 
highest high (3,25) 
lowest low (6,20)
 highest high (9,36) 
lowest low (10,22) 
highest high (14,45) 
lowest low (15,30) 
end (17,35) 
essentially if this is a line graph, the peaks and troughs over a period of time are expected as output.

Comment: Which functions in "other RDBMS" are you referring to? The result you want can easily be done using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)

Comment: For example, match_recognize ...I am aware of window functions but I am not sure if  the expected output I am looking for can be obtained just with the window functions. If there is something I am missing, please let me know...

Comment: e.g. like this: https://rextester.com/ZJDZW36048

Comment: Thanks for the sample but perhaps I did not give a complete picture on the sample dataset... So here is one... with a few more line items as sample.............  
 (1  , 23),
(2  , 24),
(3  , 25),
(4  , 22),
(5  , 21),
(6  , 20),
(7  , 30),
(8  , 32),
(9  , 36),
(10 , 22),
(11, 25),
(12,28),
(13,30),
(14,45),
(15,30),
(16,34),
(17,35);


output
start (1,23)
highest high (3,25)
lowest low (6,20)
highest high (9,36)
lowest low (10,22)
highest high (14,45)
lowest low (15,30)
end  (17,35)

essentially if this is a line graph, the peak and trough is expected.

Comment: How do I edit the formatting to be nice, I am unable to edit it in the comment box.to make it readable.... please let me know so I will make it look easier to read..

Comment: Do not post additional information in comments. [edit] your question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name He is refering to MATCH_RECOGNIZE https://modern-sql.com/feature/match_recognize it could not be "easily" translated to window functions(at least some more complex patterns are cumbersome when rewritten with multi step cte)